"std::bad_alloc" error when trying to load microdata
I'm using "PNADcIBGE" package to download microdata from Brazillian national household research. But it always fails and shows me this error: std::bad_alloc.
The package has a function called "get_pnadc" for downloading such data where you select a certain questionaire. I only get this trouble when I download a specific questionaire for any year: which is "topic = 2". For example:
pnadc_2016 <- PNADcIBGE::get_pnadc(year=2016, topic=2, design=FALSE)
The function performs 3 essential stages. In the first stage, the function downloads the requested raw data in ".txt", which is around 3.5 GB. In the second one, it downloads a very light ".txt" file with variable's inputs. The final stage should return a data frame with data from the raw data organized according to the input text file. The problem arises in this stage, where I get std::bad_alloc.
This happens although I have, say, more than 30 GB free in my computer.
There is also an offline import function from this same package but the problem remains the same. That is: I manually downloaded the .txt files, but the problem persisted. What am I missing?

I'd recommend to ask the author at the package's github.
